# Check if string is null and if it is replace it (C#)

Tags: c#, arrays, string

I have following code :

```
var resultToReturn = (from i in lstOverview
                              select new string[]
                              {
                i.num.ToString(),
                i.name,
                DataAccess.data.getGameType(i.type),
                i.dateComingOut.Value.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture),
                i.userLastUpdated.ToString(),
                i.freeOrPay.ToString(),
                $"<div><a href='{editLink + "/" + i.id}' class='btn btn-primary'>Edit</a></div>"
                              }).ToArray();
```

I need to be able to check if `i.dateComingOut` is null or not and if it is, replace it with "n/a".

What's the best way to achieve this?

Can we do it in the select itself?

Comment: look up the null coalescing operator.

Comment: ^and the null conditional operator.

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/conditional-operator

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
var resultToReturn = (from i in lstOverview
                          select new string[]
                          {
            i?.num.ToString(),
            i?.name,
            DataAccess.data.getGameType(i?.type),
            i?.dateComingOut?.Value.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture) ?? "n/a",
            i?.userLastUpdated.ToString(),
            i?.freeOrPay.ToString(),
            $"<div><a href='{editLink + "/" + i?.id}' class='btn btn-primary'>Edit</a></div>"
                          }).ToArray();
```

Note that you should be checking for null all over the query every time you use the i variable or you'll get a **NullReferenceException**.

Comment: I did try it but I still get an error 500 when I ask to show my datatable because I have one date with an entry of null. So it doesn't show the "n/a" instead

Comment: @Jeremy I have updated my code. The problem with your code is that if i can be null you need to use the same pattern every time you use it.

Comment: @ZackISSOIR - `i?.dateComingOut?.Value`etc, I believe?

Comment: I made it work by changing the date line to : `i.dateComingOut?.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture) ?? "n/a"`

Comment: @zzxyz if he is a DateTime it is a struct , it cannot be null.

Comment: @ZackISSOIR - `.Value` indicates it is a nullable type, I would think?: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/nullable-types/

Comment: adding 'i?' shouldn't be needed, if 'i' is null I suspect it will just assign null to resultToReturn

Comment: @Jeremy - PS- This answer and this discussion kind of demonstrates why (I think) your question got downvoted.  Anyone nice enough to answer had to make guesses about what the rest of your code looked like, and whether their answer actually worked:  https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: @xdflames, I added i? because I don't know if his list lstOverview contains the litteral null, if it is the case It will throw a NullReferenceException.